# Javascript Binary Search Tree methods not working

Tags: javascript, binary-tree

I am trying to build this simple Javascript Binary search tree. I have simply created the addItem method for the tree, but no item seems to get added to the tree. I have divided the addItem method into several other methods to ensure that the tree reference is passed properly without any errors.  I think the problem is occurring in the addNode recursive calls.

Below the is the given code:

```
class Node{
    constructor(value){
        this.value=value;
        this.left=null;
        this.right=null;
    }
    show(){
        console.log(this.value);
    }
}


class BST{
    constructor(){
        this.root=null;
    }

    addNode(node, item){
        if(node==null){
            node=new Node(item);
        }
        else if(item<=node.value){
            this.addNode(node.left, item);

        }
        else {
            this.addNode(node.right, item);
        }
    }

    addFunc(tree, item){

        this.addNode(tree.root, item);
    }

    addItem(item){
        this.addFunc(this, item);
     }


}


let bst = new BST();
bst.addItem(5);
bst.addItem(43);
bst.addNode(12);

console.log(bst); // shows BST{root:null}
```

Comment: I can see why this doesn't do anything but I'm utterly bewildered at what you're trying to accomplish.  It looks like maybe you don't realize that you have to set instance variables using `this` in JavaScript as opposed to a language like Java.  But who knows.... your code just doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @RandyCasburn the 'addFunc' has been called inside the addItem method, the idea is to just call bst.addItem(item). and inside the addItem method i did called the addFunc method

Comment: Yeah, saw it eventually, I think I was just perplexed as John stated.

Comment: @john_omalley can you rewrite the code keeping the structure that i created?

Comment: Actually in your code your not adding into `root` your node

Comment: @N.Jadhav wat about the addNode method?

Comment: you have defined this `this.root=null;` this but not used

Comment: @raiyan106 - please see my answer. I think you'll understand.

Comment: @raiyan106 Try this class I have created https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dsinjs/binary-tree it has alot of basic + extra functions

Answer (score 0):

One of the problem is in `function addNode()` at `if(node==null){node=new Node(item);}`

`node` is passed as a parameter, which means when `this.addNode(tree.root, item);` is called

1. `node.a = 5` changes value of `tree.root.a` to `5`
2. `node = 5` just changes the value of this `node` parameter to `5` but not the actual argument that is `tree.root` value is not assigned to `5`.

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Comment: I see, then how am i supposed to refer the tree.root variable in this method?

Comment: If you want to assign `root` a new reference in another function then you can pass `tree` as a parameter and and check can assign `tree.root = {}` a new value.

Comment: what if i just assign this.root={} instead of this.root=null while defining the constructor? wont it be the same thing?

Comment: I dont know BST, but only javascript. So I pointed out that problem.  Depends upon that `root` should be init with `{}` or `null`, but it wont solve problem as pointed in `addNode()`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you've not assigned anything as the root of your tree. Your intent was there with `this.root`.  Next, your logic has you recursing a method rather than recursing your tree.

While you call the `addNode()` method for each value, you always test the root of your tree for `>` and `<` values. So this code will only ever overwrite a single `.left` or `.right` value. So recursing your function internally doesn't really do what you expect.

The solution is to recurse the tree looking for the correct slot for the value that is passed into the function.

I've re-written your code a bit and taken some liberties with the API. For instance, creating a new BST will require the starting value to be passed into the constructor (this just helps simplify the code a bit).  Next, you'll notice no more recursive functions. The recursive calls are replaced with a while loop that finds the appropriate node to add the new node.

This code actually builds the tree where as your attempt only builds a single level.

**Edit** refactored into search function

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = {};
    this.right = {};
  }
  show() {
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}


class BST {
  constructor(value = 0) {
    this.root = new Node(value);
  }

  addNode(item) {
    Object.assign(this.search(item), new Node(item));
  }
  findLeftChild(item) {
    return this.search(item).left.value;
  }

  search(item) {
    let found = false;
    let foundNode = this.root;
    while (!found) {
      if (foundNode.value === item) {
        break;
      } else if (foundNode.value > item) {
        foundNode = foundNode.left;
        found = foundNode.value === undefined;
      } else if (foundNode.value < item) {
        foundNode = foundNode.right;
        found = foundNode.value === undefined;
      }
    }
    return foundNode;
  }

  addItem(item) {
    this.addNode(item);
  }
}


let bst = new BST(5);
bst.addItem(43);
bst.addItem(12);
bst.addItem(6);
bst.addItem(66);
bst.addItem(22);
bst.addItem(4);
bst.addItem(3);
bst.addItem(2);
bst.addItem(1);

console.log("Found: 17 ", bst.search(17).value !== undefined);
console.log("find value less than 12: " + bst.findLeftChild(12));
console.log(JSON.stringify(bst, null, 2)); // shows BST{root:null}
```